# Collisions in custom physics problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm kind of new to Unity. As by the title, I am having trouble getting the collisions right in my game. I am using the custom physics script from unity: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/scripting-gravity?playlist=17093. In my game, I am experiencing difficulties in disable collisions.

For example, when I use

```cs
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (8, 9);
```

It doesn't change anything and the two characters still collide. Also, for some reasons, the triggers behave strange and are still affected by collisions. Going near a character with triggers will make him float up. I've been stuck on this for a long time and I'd really appreciate the help.

It is worth noting that I am using custom physics and using a box collider 2d to detect attack ranges etc. Here is some code of that:

```cs
Collider2D attackbox = Physics2D.OverlapBox (attackPos.position, new Vector2 (attackRangeX, attackRangeY), 0, whatIsPlayer); 
if (attackbox != null && !isDead && characterController.isDead == false) {
    targetVelocity = Vector2.zero;
    animator.SetTrigger ("isPunching");
    timeBtwAtk = startTimeBtwAtk;
}
```

and I have individual punch triggers in the animation to detect when the character is actually being hit:

```cs
public void SetColliderIndex(int spriteNum)
{
    colliders[currentColliderIndex].enabled = false;
    currentColliderIndex = spriteNum;
    colliders[currentColliderIndex].enabled = true;
}

public void ClearColliderIndex()
{
    colliders[currentColliderIndex].enabled = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Player") 
    {
        col.GetComponent<CharacterController2D> ().TakeDamage (enemyDamage);
        col.GetComponent<CharacterController2D> ().canWait = false;
        col.GetComponent<CharacterController2D> ().canControl = false;
    }
}
```

When I use `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (8, 9);` I want both specified layers not to interact whatsoever. I don't want any weird shifts, or floating when they pass through each other. Also when I move my player agains the enemy, I don't want him to be able to push him back. I want it to be as if he is running into a wall.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered something similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387846/unity2d-ignore-collision-with-edge-collider/55392222#55392222). Also, if you don't want the player suddenly floating upon collision, you can just set the rigidbody/rigidbody2d type to kinematic, but this mean the object will not be affected by physics. you will have to do that in code.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I already have kinematic rigidbody enabled. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is that at some point the two colliders interact and/or one of the two gets activated back, but from the code that you posted i can't clearly identify the problem if there's any